# Cannot run executable jar packaged with Maven and Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jersey

I'm trying to package my webapp in a fat jar in order to be executed with `java -jar my-app.jar`. Everything works when I do `mvn spring-boot:run` but when I try to run the packaged jar with:

```
$ mvn clean package
$ java -jar target/my-app.jar
```

Spring Boot logo is shown but afer 3 or 4 seconds, it stops, without start any server.

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.digitalmenu</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDITED**

After enable logs, I see this error:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServlet
>   ContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
>
> Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL...

I have a class `JserseyConfig`...

I have tried [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1345) but still not working...

Comment: When the app starts via "java -jar my.file.jar" then spring should have done a good job and maven too. The error must be in your java code?!

Comment: The POM looks more or less fine except for `<goal>repackage</goal>` [missing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html). What does the log say?

Comment: @lexicore No logs. I mean, it's like when server is started when after 3 seconds, it stops, prompt is shown, nothing happens. I have edited the question

Comment: have you enabled debug (or even trace) level on the loggers? If not, please enable and try again, see if something more is logged.

Comment: Start your app with `--debug` or `--trace` to get debug/trace output.

Comment: Everything works when I run it with Maven. Problem is when I try to run it with `java -jar`. It starts and after 3 seconds, it stops. How can debug that?

Comment: How about a [thread dump](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14119817/521799) of your JVM and post the blocking thread here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer! Thanks to the comment of the OP in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875379/single-jar-startup-failed-after-upgrade-from-spring-boot-1-3-7-to-1-4-0) question's accepted answer.

I was registering the Jersey resources with:

```
packages("com.myapp.resources");
```

Registering each one individually everything works:

```
register(Res1.class);
register(Res2.class);
...
```